# Create heroku app from codeship's custom script

Tags: bash, heroku, sh, heroku-toolbelt, codeship

I'm trying to create a heroku-application in Codeship's custom script but I can't understand how to login on heroku programmatically.

Is it possible to pass email and password to `heroku login` command?
Or maybe I can setup ssh-key to do this?

Something like `heroku login -e email@email.com -p qwerty` or `heroku login -f ./ssh_key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution: an environment variable HEROKU_API_KEY do that for us.